# How can I loop through an array while averaging the values of one element and only keep the newly averaged field in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, group-by, average, unset

I have database that contains scores which are stored daily. I want to average each months scores for each user. So far I have this:

DB structure:

```
id | name    | tscore            | added 

int| string  | float(100 or less)| date(2014-01-01 16:34:22)
```

Code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getChartData)){ // Data from MySQL
    $added_date = explode(' ',$row['added']); // Date formate 2014-01-01 16:34:22
    $chartData[] = array(
        'id'     => $row['name'],
        'tscore' => $row['tscore'],
        'added'  => $added_date[0] // Here I take the month only
    );
}
if($_POST['range'] == 'month'){
    foreach($chartData as $key => $value){
        $added = explode('-',$chartData[$key]['added']);
        $count = 1;
        foreach($chartData as $key2 => $value2){
            $added2 = explode('-',$chartData[$key2]['added']);
            if($chartData[$key]['id'] === $chartData[$key2]['id'] && $added[1] === $added2[1]){ // if user is the same and the month is the same, add the scores together, increment counter, and unset 2nd instance
                $chartData[$key]['tscore'] = ((float)$chartData[$key]['tscore'] + (float)$chartData[$key2]['tscore']);
                $count++;
                unset($chartData[$key2]);
            }     
        }
        $chartData[$key]['tscore'] = ($chartData[$key]['tscore']/$count); // Average all the scores for the month.
    }
}
```

The problem is this method is deleting all the elements of the `$chartData` array. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: A side note, `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` and prepared statement/variable binding for better future. And since you need average...any chance you can directly use database function for that?

Comment: Please show the database struncture, this can probably be achieved with SQL

Comment: @Passerby thank you for your comment, I'll start using mysqli instead. Regarding using the database funciton, I wouldn't mind, problem is how would I do that?

Comment: Look into PDO rather than mysqli_*. It took  while for me to get used to, but in the long run it is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to solve it with MySQL. Try something like this (replace 'your_scores_table' with your table name):

```
SELECT
    Score.name, 
    AVG(Score.tscore) AS `avg`,
    CONCAT(YEAR(Score.added), '-', MONTH(Score.added)) AS `year_month`
FROM 
    your_scores_table AS Score
GROUP BY 
    Score.name ASC, 
    YEAR(Score.added) DESC, 
    MONTH(Score.added) DESC
;
```

Comment: Sorry, had some typos in the code. Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong.  You are looping through the same array twice.  Which means that the following `if` will **always evaluate to true** which means that array item will always get unset

```
//This will always be true
if($chartData[$key]['id'] === $chartData[$key2]['id'] && $added[1] === $added2[1]){
```

It may be simpler for you to create another array where you keep your scores.  Something like

```
$aScores = array();
$count = 1;
foreach($chartData as $key => $value){

    //Add score to a different array
    $aScores[$value['name']]['tscore'] = (($aScores[$value['name']]['tscore'] + $value['tscore']) / $count);

    $count++;
}
```

Also I would look into the MySQL [AVG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function.  You could use that to save you having to do it in PHP

Comment: Thank you for your great answer and suggestion. If I could accept both answers I would also accept yours. Thanks again